# Problems Importing Bootstrap Studio Renders into React with reactstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap, bootstrap-studio

I'm working on a project where the designer is working with BootStrap studio, which exports to html with BootStrap 4, and I'm converting the exported file into React components with reactstrap.

I'm facing problems with class and styling rules, since the original file inherit from 7 different files. What's the best way to convert something like:

```
         <div id="nav-bars">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" id="top-nav" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);color:rgb(255,255,255);">
            <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="background-image:url(&quot;assets/img/logoalt copy.png&quot;);padding-right:5px;background-size:contain;margin-right:0;padding-left:5px;background-position:center;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

into react components while preserving the css rules?

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding the actual problem. `jsx` provides the `className` and `style` prop to set class names and inline styles on elements. But what is the benefit of creating react components from static markup?

Answer (score 1):

JSX requires that you className=  not class=

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html